# efibootmgr doesn't match what's really used on MacBook Air

Tags: boot, uefi, macbook-air, refind

I'm on a MacBookAir5,2 (2012) and I've been running Ubuntu along side Mac OS X for some time. I used rEFIt when I first installed Ubuntu and that worked fine.

As I started working with Docker, I outgrew the disk space available and decided to get a new SSD drive. I did that, swapped the disks and installed Ubuntu 14.10.

After this point, I've fiddled with rEFInd (as rEFIt is not maintained) and I've read lot of [Rod Smith's pages](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/features.html)

However, now I want Ubuntu only and won't boot anything else on this machine. But somehow, what I think I tell `efibootmgr` to do, it won't. The problem is that rEFInd isn't run after booting. The only way I can boot my system is pressing the alt-key on booting, and selecting rEFInd on a USB stick. This works just fine though, no issues at all with that approach - it's just a bit inconvenient. :-)

If I boot without the USB stick attached, all I get is the grey screen with nothing being displayed. It stays grey "forever" (I've not waited much longer than 20 minutes).

My SSD contains four partitions:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: hybrid
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with hybrid MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 937703088 sectors, 447.1 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): B30ED5AD-A6B6-4FF9-9CC4-1F440536FB9F
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 937703054
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 264949 sectors (129.4 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2          409640       195722143   93.1 GiB    AF00  Macintosh HD
   3       195985408       921180159   345.8 GiB   EF00  LINUX
   4       921180160       937701375   7.9 GiB     0700  SWAP
```

and I actually wiped out all files in the ESP as a measure to narrow down the issue. What I have now is `efibootmgr` reporting:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000
Boot0000* rEFInd Boot Manager   HD(1,28,64000,7fa6ae3f-d9a7-4411-838a-1d0133b9993a)File(\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi)
BootFFFF*   ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1f,2)SATA(0,0,0)HD(2,64028,e066090,00007690-046d-0000-175e-0000ca5e0000)File(\System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi)
```

and

```
root@fredrik-mbair:~# tree /boot/efi/ | grep -v png
/boot/efi/
└── EFI
    ├── refind
    │   ├── icons
    │   ├── keys
    │   │   ├── altlinux.cer
    │   │   ├── canonical-uefi-ca.der
    │   │   ├── fedora-ca.cer
    │   │   ├── openSUSE-UEFI-CA-Certificate.cer
    │   │   ├── refind.cer
    │   │   └── SLES-UEFI-CA-Certificate.cer
    │   ├── refind.conf
    │   └── refind_x64.efi
    └── tools

5 directories, 68 files
```

Last piece of information is this: When I boot with USB stick detached and press alt, I get one (1) hard drive icon with the text Windows under it. If I select that one, the screen blacks out and I get a white blinking cursor (underline character) in the top left corner of the screen, like 80x25 lines or similar console. Nothing happens after that.
The "rEFInd Boot Manager" option doesn't appear.

I have no idea where the "Windows" option comes from, and I don't know what the FFFF option is either.

```
root@fredrik-mbair:~# efibootmgr -b FFFF -B
invalid hex value FFFF
```

Since I won't use anything but a single Ubuntu OS and Linux kernel, I would be fine with gummiboot but I'm not sure how that's going to help when `efibootmgr` can't get rEFInd to be run at boot ...

Last attempt at running `install.sh` (installed from PPA) gives this output:

```
root@fredrik-mbair:~# /usr/share/refind/install.sh 
Installing rEFInd on Linux....
ESP was found at /boot/efi using vfat
Found rEFInd installation in /boot/efi/EFI/refind; upgrading it.
Copied rEFInd binary files

Notice: Backed up existing icons directory as icons-backup.
Existing refind.conf file found; copying sample file as refind.conf-sample
to avoid overwriting your customizations.

rEFInd has been set as the default boot manager.
Existing //boot/refind_linux.conf found; not overwriting.

Installation has completed successfully.
```

I have no idea on where to go next.

Comment: The "Windows" option is for booting the USB stick in BIOS-emulation mode.  The Mac's boot manager labels that as "Windows"

Answer (score 1):

So this is what I did in order to get somewhere:

First attempt was this:

- remove everything under /boot/efi
- blank out the Hybrid MBR (using `gdisk`, expert menu, then `n` then `w`)
- `/usr/share/refind/install.sh`
- `efibootmgr -c -l \\EFI\\refind\\... -L TIRED`

This actually got rEFInd to run after reboot. However, it didn't detect the `vmlinuz-3.16.0-28-generic.efi.signed` kernel that I want to run. It showed to options and both lead to `No bootable device` in a 80x25 console.

Aha, so I tried re-running the `install.sh` script with `--alldrivers`. After a reboot, I'm back at the grey screen that never shows anything.

Rebooted, went for rEFInd from my USB stick and then:

- wiped out the `/boot/efi` partition
- copied everything from the USB stick onto `/boot/efi`
- created a new entry (deleting the old) with `efibootmgr`

And how I have a working system.

Details:

```
root@fredrik-mbair:~# gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 937703088 sectors, 447.1 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): B30ED5AD-A6B6-4FF9-9CC4-1F440536FB9F
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 937703054
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 264949 sectors (129.4 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2          409640       195722143   93.1 GiB    AF00  Macintosh HD
   3       195985408       921180159   345.8 GiB   EF00  LINUX
   4       921180160       937701375   7.9 GiB     0700  SWAP
```

```
/boot/efi/
├── EFI
│   └── boot
│       ├── bootia32.efi
│       ├── bootx64.efi
│       ├── drivers_ia32
│       │   ├── btrfs_ia32.efi
│       │   ├── ext2_ia32.efi
│       │   ├── ext4_ia32.efi
│       │   ├── hfs_ia32.efi
│       │   ├── iso9660_ia32.efi
│       │   ├── LICENSE_GPL.txt
│       │   ├── LICENSE.txt
│       │   └── reiserfs_ia32.efi
│       ├── drivers_x64
│       │   ├── btrfs_x64.efi
│       │   ├── ext2_x64.efi
│       │   ├── ext4_x64.efi
│       │   ├── hfs_x64.efi
│       │   ├── iso9660_x64.efi
│       │   ├── LICENSE_GPL.txt
│       │   ├── LICENSE.txt
│       │   └── reiserfs_x64.efi
│       ├── icons
│       └── refind.conf
├── shellia32.efi
└── shellx64.efi

5 directories, 81 files
```

```
root@fredrik-mbair:~# efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000
Boot0000* COPY  HD(1,28,64000,7fa6ae3f-d9a7-4411-838a-1d0133b9993a)File(\EFI\boot\bootx64.efi)
BootFFFF*   ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1f,2)SATA(0,0,0)HD(2,64028,e066090,00007690-046d-0000-175e-0000ca5e0000)File(\System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi)
```